# Items not showing up in my view cart page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an e-commerce website for the school project that fetches information from a database I created. Unfortunately this was the code we were partially given and I can't get the items added to the shopping cart to show in the check out page.

Here is the code for the main page

```
<div class="products">
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, price FROM products");
if($results){
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
    <li class="product">
    <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
    <div class="product-content"><h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
    <div class="product-desc">{$obj->product_desc}</div>
    <div class="product-info">
    Price {$currency}{$obj->price}

    <fieldset>

    <label>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
    </label>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
    <div align="center"><button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button></div>
    </div></div>
    </form>
    </li>
EOT;
}
$products_item .= '</ul>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>
</div>

<div class="shopping-cart">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"])>0)
{
    echo '<div class="cart-view-table-front" id="view-cart">';
    echo '<h3>Your Shopping Cart</h3>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
    echo '<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<tbody>';

    $total =0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
        $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
        $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        echo '<td>Qty <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /> Remove</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '<td colspan="4">';
    echo '<button type="submit">Update</button><a href="view_cart.php" class="button">Checkout</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';

    $current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';

}
?>
</div>
```

This is the update cart php file

```
<?php
session_start(); //start session
include_once("config.php"); //include config file

//add product to session or create new one
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add' && $_POST["product_qty"]>0)
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ //add all post vars to new_product array
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    //remove unecessary vars
    unset($new_product['type']);
    unset($new_product['return_url']);

    //we need to get product name and price from database.
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT product_name, price FROM products");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $new_product['product_code']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name, $price);

    while($statement->fetch()){

        //fetch product name, price from db and add to new_product array
        $new_product["product_name"] = $product_name;
        $new_product["product_price"] = $price;

        if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])){  //if session var already exist
            if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']])) //check item exist in products array
            {
                unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']]); //unset old array item
            }
        }
        $_SESSION["cart_products"][$new_product['product_code']] = $new_product; //update or create product session with new item
    }
}


//update or remove items
if(isset($_POST["product_qty"]) || isset($_POST["remove_code"]))
{
    //update item quantity in product session
    if(isset($_POST["product_qty"]) && is_array($_POST["product_qty"])){
        foreach($_POST["product_qty"] as $key => $value){
            if(is_numeric($value)){
                $_SESSION["cart_products"][$key]["product_qty"] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    //remove an item from product session
    if(isset($_POST["remove_code"]) && is_array($_POST["remove_code"])){
        foreach($_POST["remove_code"] as $key){
            unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$key]);
        }
    }
}

//back to return url
$return_url = (isset($_POST["return_url"]))?urldecode($_POST["return_url"]):''; //return url
header('Location:'.$return_url);
```

And finally, the checkout page php file

```
<div class="cart-view-table-back">
<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th>Remove</th></tr></thead>
  <body>
    <?php

  $total = 0; //set initial total value
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) //check session var
    {

        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
            //set variables to use in content below
            $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
            $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
            $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
            $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
            $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);

            echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$currency.$product_price.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$currency.$subtotal.'</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $total = ($total + $subtotal); //add subtotal to total var
        }
        }
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;">Amount Payable : <?php echo "$".sprintf("%01.2f", $total);?></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><a href="index.php" class="button">Add More Items</a><button type="submit">Update</button></td></tr>
  </body>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $current_url; ?>" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I would first check what actually is in `$_SESSION["cart_products"]`, either the new products aren't added, or they aren't shown. It's not easy for us to look at the code and decide what happens. If the products are added then we only need to look at the checkout page. I suppect however, they are never really added.

Comment: What are you binding to SQL? I would recommend to check if you have switched MySQLi exception mode

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution finally,

Only had to add session_start() in my checkout page php file.